# Cannot upload a file with graphql-upload and formik

Tags: reactjs, graphql, formik, react-dropzone

I'm trying to upload an image with React-dropzone through Formik.

When I send this image, I use it to [preview](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/#previews) it on a img html, which works great.

When I do click in send, the preview object is only sended, the rest of info disappear...

[image]

I don't know if is for formik, because when I print the values, it gives me the right info, but when is sent, everything changes.

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/rujlsPTnmu8) about this problem, and here's a little [example that was deleted, the answer is below](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/bug-upload).

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is your `Mutation` type:

```
type Mutation {
  uploadFile(file: Upload!): Boolean!
}
```

Your schema defines the `uploadFile` file as taking a single argument called `file` of the type `Upload!`. The `!` means the argument is non-null, i.e. null cannot be passed as a value to it.

This is your query:

```
mutation UploadFileMutation($file: Upload) {
  uploadFile(file: $file)
}
```

You're passing a variable, $file, to the argument `file`, but you've told GraphQL that this variable is of the type `Upload`, not `Upload!`. In other words, you're saying that `$file` *could* be null. According to the spec, this fails type validation.

From the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-All-Variable-Usages-are-Allowed):

> Variable usages must be compatible with the arguments they are passed to. Validation failures occur when variables are used in the context of types that are complete mismatches, or if a nullable type in a variable is passed to a non‐null argument type.

In other words, if the field is `Upload!`, you can only use variables that are also defined to be `Upload!`. If the field were of the type `Upload`, you could pass in either `Upload!` or `Upload`.

**TLDR;** Change your query to:

```
mutation UploadFileMutation($file: Upload!) {
  uploadFile(file: $file)
}
```

or, if the file *could* be null, update your field's type to be nullable.

Comment: Awesome! It works, but... Only sends me `{ preview:
   'blob:http://localhost:3000/72474e2f-ddd3-43e1-8ea6-567714ed4ad5' }` not the file...

Comment: I've updated the repo with the mismatch problem... But it's not enough because the response is `{ preview: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/72474e2f-ddd3-43e1-8ea6-567714ed4ad5' }` and I want the file sended...

Comment: That should really be a separate question, as it has nothing to do with the error you were seeing. That said, you need to correctly configure your client to send the file. This is normally done by creating a link with [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client). Please see that project for additional details.

Comment: Your repo is using `apollo-boost`, which doesn't include an upload link and doesn't let you add additional links. You'll need to migrate to apollo-client (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration.html) and add the upload link from apollo-upload-client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mismatch between your mutation operation and your schema.

The mutation operation accepts a `null` value but the schema does not; so the operation fails the validation step.

Change this line to `Upload!`: https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/bug-upload/blob/master/client/src/App.js#L8

Or, change your schema to `Upload` if you want to allow the file to be nullable.

Comment: Awesome! It works, but... Only sends me `{ preview:
   'blob:http://localhost:3000/72474e2f-ddd3-43e1-8ea6-567714ed4ad5' }` not the file...

Comment: I've updated the repo with the mismatch problem... But it's not enough because the response is `{ preview: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/72474e2f-ddd3-43e1-8ea6-567714ed4ad5' }` and I want the file sended...